# How do I fix my minecraft? It says its not executable

Tags: java, launcher, minecraft, executable

The file `/home/sean/.minecraft/launcher.jar` is not marked as executable.

I get this error whenever I try to load the `launcher.jar` in my `.minecraft` folder but then when I right-click, `properties`, `permissions` and tick `Allow executing file as program` it doesn't do anything, doesn't load anything or say anything:

> If this was downloaded or copied from an untrusted source, it may be
>   dangerous to run.  For more details, read about the executable bit.

I got it from http://www.minecraft.net.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to install Java.**

To do install it, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, And then run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

And to check Java version, run:

```
java -version
```

To set Java to default, run:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```